# How to find out what files changed in a given git commit?

Tags: git

I am troubleshooting a problem where something that used to work, does not, all of a sudden. Given a `sha1`, how can i find out what files changed as part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show --name-only <the-hex-sha1-string>` should do the trick.
Here I assume that `sha1` you mention is the sha1 signature of the commit.

Consider reading about `git bisect` for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Any of these should work:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <COMMIT_SHA1>

git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <COMMIT_SHA1>
```

Example output:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

To also show the status of each file in the change, use `--name-status` option instead:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r <COMMIT_SHA1>

git show --pretty="format:" --name-status <COMMIT_SHA1>
```

Example output:

```
A     foo
M     bar
D     baz
```

Answer (score 1):

[`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) actually involves [`git diff-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree), and it has improved with Git 2.22 (Q2 2019).

The final report from "`git bisect`" used to show the suspected culprit using a raw "`diff-tree`", with which there is no output for a merge commit.
This has been updated to use a more modern and human readable output that still is concise enough.

See [commit b02be8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b02be8b901bc65de1b75014c0dade67b233569ff), [commit 40ae3d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40ae3d3eeae95f201d5532cb114266ad8f6d4130), [commit 2008f29](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2008f29093ba46e513ca2af7f14f3b75faa7a358) (22 Feb 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1b8f4dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b8f4dc580432107693a780010c240c2b676ff30), 20 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `bisect`: make `diff-tree` output prettier
>
> After completing a bisection, we print out the commit we found using an internal version of `diff-tree`.
>
> The result is aesthetically lacking:
>
> - it shows a raw diff, which is generally less informative for human
>     readers than "`--stat --summary`" (which we already decided was nice
>     for humans in format-patch's output).
> - by not abbreviating hashes, the result is likely to wrap on most
>     people's terminals
> - we don't use "`-r`", so if the commit touched files in a directory,
>     you only get to see the top-level directory mentioned
> - we don't specify "`--cc`" or similar, so merges print nothing (not
>     even the commit message!)
>
> Even though bisect might be driven by scripts, there's no reason to consider this part of the output as machine-readable (if anything, the initial "`$hash` is the first bad commit" might be parsed, but we won't touch that here).
>   Let's make it prettier and more informative for a human reading the output.
>
> While we're tweaking the options, let's also switch to using the diff "`ui`" config.
>   If we're accepting that this is human-readable output, then we should respect the user's options for how to display it.